# Grunt cli install error for windows

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to install Grunt cli for windows using command "npm install -g grunt-cli" getting bellow mentioned error message, please suggest me on this.

**

```
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\M1022339
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\M1022339\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**

Thanks,
Dhananjaya

Answer (score 0):

solved:

we need to set proxy server url for command window.

set HTTP_PROXY=http : // UserName:password@proxy_server_IP:port

for example : set HTTP_PROXY= http : // xyz:Abc123@ip:port

after setting run "npm install -g grunt-cli" command